# 7-meter cable between gas meter and microcontroller: too long?

Tags: microcontroller, cables, low-power, low-voltage

My gas meter has two GND / PULSE pins that trigger a short pulse (probably +3V or +5V) each time 0.010 ㎥ has been used, for use with [domotic equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_automation). There is no power plug in this basement, and I don't want to run an Arduino with batteries, HF / WiFi etc.
An option would be:

```
 Gas Meter <--------- 7-meter wires --------> Arduino or ESP8266 -> power plug
 (GND / PULSE)
```

If I remember correctly the meter has an internal cell battery that lasts 10+ years (that I can't change myself of course, only the gas company can do this).

**Can the length of these wires be a potential problem?** Will the microcontroller receive a nice 0-5 V rising/falling edge signal?

Comment: If not considering an opto-isolator, consider a TVS or transient voltage suppressor on such a long cable.  Any number of things can create an EM pulse which this cable will readily pickup, and if strong enough, could damage your micro.  A TVS has a little capacitance, so this could further slow down a weak/short pulse.

Comment: Which gas meter it is? Does it have a manual which describes the output signal, electrically, including the pulse polarity?

Comment: I am assuming the meter is owned by the gas company and there are laws against tampering with it. Anything you do to increase the battery drain will shorten its lifespan. What are the output terminals connected to? Can you post a schematic of the electronics. It would be best to contact the gas company, explain what you want and how you can get the information you want.

Comment: What’s _”domotic equipment”_?

Comment: @Gil It is not "tampering with it". The gas meter has a two-pin plug, well accessible to the end user (no need to open it, of course that would be illegal), to connect home automation equipment.

Comment: @Basj if you drain the battery prematurely, I think that may be considered "tampering with it".

Comment: @winny, I thought *domotic* was a misspelling of 'domestic' but I got that wrong. The link explains it. Every day's a schoolday and all that :-)

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem, because whatever type output the meter has, you have to bring some wires or cable between the Arduino and gas meter anyway, so you can also bring power and include necessary buffering circuitry and maybe isolation for the gas meter output.

But before making any connections, you need to figure out what the gas meter outputs. If it is a battery powered meter, it might not output a logic or voltage pulse directly, it may already be just the output terminals of an opto-isolator as then it would not have any effect on the internal battery.

Comment: Totally underrated answer. The idea to isolate/condition signal at the source is an elegant solution that only adds couple wires (or a wire and a shield) but removes all worries and is suitable for much longer runs too. Although there should be at least TVS on the receiving end nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the length of these wires be a potential problem?

Yes, definitely. Depending on current consumption you will have a voltage drop and also it will be very prone to pick up EMI. It depends heavily on what environment you got, of course. Also, shielded cable or not makes a big difference as well.

Consider using a *current loop* or a similar suitable, rugged signal instead.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can the length of these wires be a potential problem? Will the
> microcontroller receive a nice 0V - 5V rising/falling edge signal?*

I think it's worth a try. If the pulses are not too short in duration i.e. greater than 1 μs in time then I think it should work but, make sure your MCU can read the pulse if it is this short.

To give it a higher chance of success use an opto-coupler at the receiving end so that gas meter ground and MCU ground are isolated.

Comment: I have various RL anecdotes of similar failed projects where using TTL levels for such long wires was a bad mistake. Although that's from industrial or automotive environments. If this sits in some office environment then maybe it will work. At least until someone mounts a Wifi router next to it or such...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I'm correct the pulse is 300ms long

Comment: @Lundin It may begin as a TTL level signal but I'm suggesting that an opto-isolator be used at the MCU end and, that paints a different picture to what you are suggesting. Given that the op has revealed that the pulse is 300 ms long, I think your comment may be somewhat pessimistic. I've designed gas meter pulse interfaces as well as optical interfaces to electricity meters if experience is to be regarded as beneficial or anecdotally relevant

Comment: I did a project where we had an optical sensor using 5V levels and PWM pulses, shielded copper cable. It worked fine in production for many years until someone mounted the cable next to a high current device and then suddenly mysterious errors started to appear. Not sure if it was radiated or conducted emissions but the cause was definitely EMI.